# how can i make a remove all items in my cart

Tags: php, sql

i've been searching on how can i make a remove all items, can you guys help me? the only thing i manage to make is remove a single item

```
if (isset($_GET["action"])){
    if ($_GET["action"] == "delete"){
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $keys => $value){
            if ($value["product_id"] == $_GET["id"]){
                unset($_SESSION["cart"][$keys]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$_SESSION["cart"] = [];`

Comment: hey man, thanks i didn't know that its that easy.